# Extract repeating pattern from multiline test using regular expression in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re

I have a multiple text from which i want to extract the lines which have the numbers.

```
aa = 'line1 text\nline 2 text\n   Header1     Header2  Header3   Header4 Header5 Header6     Header7 Header8  Header9 Header10 Header11\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\nP...  0    318478     31        6        10    62       6360      10230       0      3      2\n\n   Header1     Header2  Header3   Header4 Header5 Header6     Header7 Header8  Header9 Header10 Header11\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\nP...  0    318478     31        6        10    62       6360      10230       0      3      2'
```

For the headers i have extracted using

```
re.findall(r"\n(.*Header.*)\n", aa , re.M)[0].strip().split()
```

and i get:

```
 ['Header1', 'Header2', 'Header3', 'Header4', 'Header5', 'Header6', 'Header7', 'Header8', 'Header9', 'Header10', 'Header11']
```

I want to extract the values lines the same way. I am trying the following. but it is not working

```
re.findall(r"(\d+\s*){11}\n", aa , re.M)
```

How can i extract the number lines which have 11 numbers separated with spaces?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are doing 1 or more numbers + spaces/newline {11} times but thats not the case you need 11 digits and 1 space  `re.compile('\d{11}\s')` should help

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
import regex

aa = 'line1 text\nline 2 text\n   Header1     Header2  Header3   Header4 Header5 Header6     Header7 Header8  Header9 Header10 Header11\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\nP...  0    318478     31        6        10    62       6360      10230       0      3      2\n\n   Header1     Header2  Header3   Header4 Header5 Header6     Header7 Header8  Header9 Header10 Header11\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\nP...  0    318478     31        6        10    62       6360      10230       0      3      2'

# get list of lines
lines = aa.split("\n")

# initiate list that will contain required rows
required_lines = []

# extract header line
for line in lines:
    match = re.findall(r"Header\d+", line)
    if len(match)>0:
        required_lines.append(match)
        break

# count number of columns
num_columns = len(required_lines[0])

# find rows that contain some numbers (the count of which is equal to the number of columns)
for line in lines:
    match = regex.findall(r"((?<![^\d\s])\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=(?:\s+|$)))", line)
    if len(match)==num_columns:
        match = list(map(float, match)) # Optionally convert number-strings to float or int
        required_lines.append(match)

print(required_lines)
```

**Output:**

```
[['Header1', 'Header2', 'Header3', 'Header4', 'Header5', 'Header6', 'Header7', 'Header8', 'Header9', 'Header10', 'Header11'],
 [0.0, 318478.0, 31.0, 6.0, 10.0, 62.0, 6360.0, 10230.0, 0.0, 3.0, 2.0],
 [0.0, 318478.0, 31.0, 6.0, 10.0, 62.0, 6360.0, 10230.0, 0.0, 3.0, 2.0]]
```